# Creating a continuously running application with a switch statement

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

I have gotten an assignment where I have to run a program continuously unless a 3 is pressed in which case the program closes. If the 1 or 2 key is pressed it needs to display "Menu 1" or "Menu 2", any other key will give an error message that tells the user to press 1, 2, or 3(to exit the program).

I managed making my switch work but I'm having issues keeping the program running so that a person can enter a 1 followed by a two which is supposed to give the result:

Menu 1
Menu 2

I attempted to put the program in a loop but it did not work out very well, here's my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("*** MENU ***\n\n1. Display Menu 1\n2. Display Menu 2\n3. Exit");
        ConsoleKeyInfo uservalue = Console.ReadKey();
        string foo = uservalue.KeyChar.ToString();
        while (foo != "3")
        { 
            switch (foo)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Menu 1");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Menu 2");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection. Please enter 1, 2 or 3");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
           }

        }
```

Comment: Just move first three lines inside the loop and remove `ReadLine` in all `case` statements.

Comment: Also, I wonder why you're doing `KeyChar.ToString()`. You can use `switch (KeyChar) { case '1': ... }` just fine. Or even better, use `Key` outright.

Comment: @Konrad Kokosa if I did that the while(foo != "3") would no longer work because the part where the 3 is entered is in the loop itself. Also removing the ReadLine  statements caused the console to continuously write the text.

Comment: @bucket, but all those method calls are extremally self-explaining... for sure you must `ReadKey` once more before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there... what you do is wait for user input and only exit when 3 is pressed.

**Example**

```
string command;
do
{
    command = Console.ReadLine();
}
while(!"3".Equals(command, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```